# What't the best solution for creating subsets of a set of characters?

Tags: algorithm

I know 'best' is subjective, so according to you, what is the best solution for the following problem:

Given a string of length n (say "abc"), generate all proper subsets of the string. So, for our example, the output would be {}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {ab}, {bc}, {ac}. {abc}.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). It can be calculated [recursively and inductively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The recursive approach -- the subsets of "abc" come in two types: those which are subsets of "bc", and those which are "a" plus a subset of "bc". So if you know the subsets of "bc", it's easy.

Alternatively, a string of length n has 2^n subsets. So write two nested loops: i counts from 0 to 2^n -1 (for the subsets), and j counts from 0 to n-1 (for characters in the ith subset). Output the jth character of the string if and only if the jth bit of i is 1.

(Well, you did say that "best" was subjective...)

Answer (score 1):

Interpret a number in binary representation as indicating which elements are included in the subset. Let's assume that you have 3 elements in your set. Number 4 corresponds to 0100 in binary notation, so you will interpret this as a subset of size 1 that only includes 2nd element. This way, generating all subsets is counting up to (2^n)-1

```
    char str [] = "abc";
    int n = strlen(str); // n is number of elements in your set

    for(int i=0; i< (1 << n); i++) { // (1 << n) is equal to 2^n
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) { // For each element in the set
            if((i & (1 << j)) > 0) { // Check if it's included in this subset. (1 << j) sets the jth bit
                cout << str[j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def subsets(s):
    r = []
    a = [False] * len(s)
    while True:
        r.append("".join([s[i] for i in range(len(s)) if a[i]]))
        j = 0
        while a[j]:
            a[j] = False
            j += 1
            if j >= len(s):
                return r
        a[j] = True

print subsets("abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon the pseudo code...

```
int i = 0;
Results.push({});

While(i > Inset.Length) {
   Foreach(Set s in Results) {
    If(s.Length == i) {
       Foreach(character c in inSet)
          Results.push(s+c);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution in C++:

```cpp
set<string> power_set_recursive(string input_str)
{
    set<string> res;
    if(input_str.size()==0) {
        res.insert("");
    } else if(input_str.size()==1) {
        res.insert(input_str.substr(0,1));
    } else {
        for(int i=0;i<input_str.size();i++) {
            set<string> left_set=power_set_iterative(input_str.substr(0,i));
            set<string> right_set=power_set_iterative(input_str.substr(i,input_str.size()-i));
            for(set<string>::iterator it1=left_set.begin();it1!=left_set.end();it1++) {
                for(set<string>::iterator it2=right_set.begin();it2!=right_set.end();it2++) {
                    string tmp=(*it1)+(*it2);
                    sort(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
                    res.insert(tmp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Iterative solution in C++:

```cpp
set<string> power_set_iterative(string input_str)
{
    set<string> res;
    set<string> out_res;
    res.insert("");
    set<string>::iterator res_it;
    for(int i=0;i<input_str.size();i++){
        for(res_it=res.begin();res_it!=res.end();res_it++){
                string tmp=*res_it+input_str.substr(i,1);
                sort(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
                out_res.insert(tmp);
        }
        res.insert(input_str.substr(i,1));
        for(set<string>::iterator res_it2=out_res.begin();res_it2!=out_res.end();res_it2++){
            res.insert(*res_it2);
    }
    out_res.clear();
    }
    return res;
}
```